# URI.SafeIframeRegexp doesn't allow YouTube video with HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm trying to allow youtube video with HTMLPurifier with that code:

```
require_once __DIR__.
'/lib/HTMLPurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config - > set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('data' => true)); //autoriser les image base64
$config - > set('HTML.MaxImgLength', null); //autoriser les dimensions en %
$config - > set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$config - > set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%.+%'); //allow everything to test
$config - > set('HTML.Trusted', true); //trying
$config - > set('HTML.SafeObject', true); //also trying that

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$html = $purifier - > purify($html);
```

But the iframe are saved without `src`.

Comment: Just a quick flyby comment - `URI.AllowedSchemes` is a whitelist, so if you set it to `['data' => true]`, you're disallowing all other schemas (like http, https, etc), even if they are by default considered safe. See if changing that helps?

Comment: I added `'https' => true` to `URI.AllowedSchemes` and that works, thank you

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, then. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

`URI.AllowedSchemes` is a whitelist, which you're overwriting to include only the `data` schema here:

```
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('data' => true));
```

To be able to use youtube URLs, you'll want to add `https` to the array at the very least.

For what it's worth, the [default whitelist](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.AllowedSchemes) is:

```
array (
  'http' => true,
  'https' => true,
  'mailto' => true,
  'ftp' => true,
  'nntp' => true,
  'news' => true,
  'tel' => true,
)
```

Remember to remove these settings again, too:

```
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
$config->set('HTML.SafeObject', true);
```

And tighten up your regex for `URI.SafeIframeRegexp`.